# Make a variable with a combination of multiple variable

Tags: php, javascript, html, sql, forms

I have a question. To make things more clear, I will give an example:

Values are submited in a form. I have:

```
Value1: Blanc
Value2: Titanium
Value3: 100
Value4: 150
Value5: China
```

I want to get a value 6 that has this structure:

```
BLTIT-100150-CH
```

Value6 has: (2 chars from value1) + (3 chars from value5) +(-)+(value3+value4 +(-)+(2 chars of value5).
Is there way to make that with PHP Or JavaScript?

Comment: read this : http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: It is not clear what you're trying to do here. Try explaining a bit more and give more background information.

Comment: your search keywords are: `string`, `concatenation` and `substring`

Comment: something like [value1.substr(0,2), value2....].join('-')

Comment: @diEcho: This question is about how to concatenate strings, use substrings, and switching case...not variable variables.

Comment: @diEcho - KarolyHorvath is suggesting that the link you cited would just confuse the OP.  I agree.  PHP variables are simple, PHP arrays are simple, PHP string concatenation and string parsing is simple.  The OP can find much better references for any of these to answer his question.  IMHO...

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php would be the proper link, and http://php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php

Comment: substr should be used with iconv / intl since the substr function is just byte based http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv-substr.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PHP:

```
$Value6 = strtoupper(substr($Value1,0,2) . substr($Value2,0,3) . '-' . 
                     $Value3 . $Value4 . '-' . substr($Value5,0,2)
                    );
```

Of course, this assumes your variables are set locally. If you're getting them straight from the POST, you need `$_POST['Value1']` instead of `$Value1`, etc.

Look up `substr` -  it takes a subsection of a string (known as a substring), given a starting point and a length.: 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

The `.` is the PHP string concatenation operator - it joins two strings together.

`strtoupper` converts a string to uppercase (see http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtoupper.php)

Comment: Thank you,this was usful for me

Comment: No problem :) Glad I could be of some help.

Comment: @Travesty3 - thanks for the correction, I'd missed that one!

Answer (score 0):

A combination of substr() and the concatenation (.) operator in PHP will parse that out.

For instance, `substr($_POST['Value 1'],0,2);` Will get the first two chars of Value 1, provided it's in that POST array.

Then just use the concat operator on the strings:

```
$val6 = $str1.$str2."-".$str3.$str4."-".$str5;
```

It's quite easy in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

With PHP, when you receive the information, you could do something like this:

```
$newValue = $_POST[Value1][0].$_POST[Value1][1];
$newValue .= $_POST[Value2][0].$_POST[Value2][1].$_POST[Value2][2]."-";
$newValue .= $_POST[Value3];
$newValue .= $_POST[Value4]."-";
$newValue .= $_POST[Value5][0].$_POST[Value5][1];
```

Comment: of course, you'll want to use strtoupper() if you want everything to be upper case. But yeah, this is the basic gist of the operation you're interested in.

Answer (score 0):

This will get you exactly what you want in PHP:

```
$value6 = strtoupper(substr($value1, 0, 2)) . strtoupper(substr($value2, 0, 3)) .
    "-{$value3}{$value4}-". strtoupper(substr($value5, 0, 2));
```

---

**EDIT :**

Since all of the characters in your resulting string (`$value6`) are uppercase, you could shorten it a bit by doing this:

```
$value6 = strtoupper(substr($value1, 0, 2) . substr($value2, 0, 3) .
    "-{$value3}{$value4}-". substr($value5, 0, 2));
```

Comment: you seem to be combining `strtoupper` and `substr` - according to http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtoupper.php, this isn't possible.

Comment: Where does it say that you can't combine them? My solution does exactly what the OP wants. Try it yourself.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I completely misread this - didn't see the `substr`s inside the strtoupper and thought you were trying to combine the functionality of the two.

Comment: @ianhales: You aren't crazy. I had forgotten them and edited the answer. Apparently not quickly enough for someone else to catch my mistake. I thought you were suggesting that you couldn't use the two together.

Comment: Phew :) I thought I'd lost it for a minute there!